# Date passed form view to controller is always "1.1.0001"

Tags: jquery, view, controller, datepicker, asp.net-mvc-5

I have my model in which I have, among other properties, DateTime property:

```
public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

I use that property in my partial view like this:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { id = "DateTextBox" })
```

And on that text box i have jquery datepicker that i bind like this:

```
$("#DateTextBox").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "Content/images/calendar.jpg",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
```

When i select date from datepicker inside textbox there is value as it should be, but
every time i submit the form date which is passed from my partial view to my controller is 
"1.1.0001" and that value is saved to my database. I have busting my head for quite some time right now and i really don't have any idea why is this happening. So please help.